# Icons and text (daycare) for "pee pee" and "poo poo" without being gross?

Tags: icon, interface-design, terminology, symbols

I have buttons where the daycare worker can select that a child went to the bathroom. They choose whether they "pee'd" or "pooped" (or however you say that in a politically correct way). I want to show icons for those while being respectful and not totally gross. I also want to show the words underneath and I cannot decide if writing "poo" and "pee" is professional. It is for daycare so that might be legit.

Comment: Just label the buttons `#1` and `#2`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

how about #1 and #2?

Or from the noun project:

this icon for [drops](http://thenounproject.com/term/drops/27130/) labled #1

and

this icon for [poop](http://thenounproject.com/term/poop/10729/) labeled #2